# DOCKER COPY not reflected in container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, logstash

Dockerfile does not copy file from gitlab directory. Below is the dockerfile,

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.16.3
USER root

RUN yum install -y curl dos2unix

COPY scripts/somefile.sh /src/app/
RUN dos2unix /src/app/somefile.sh

WORKDIR /src/app/
ENTRYPOINT ["/src/app/somefile.sh"]
```

The Project tree looks like the following,

```
C:.
├───.idea
│   └───codeStyles
├───deployment
│   ├───dev
└───scripts
│   ├───somefile.sh
```

below is deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: demo-app
  name: demo-app
  namespace: --
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: docker-image-described
          name: demo-app
          resources: ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: some-secret
              mountPath: /src/abc/secret
              readOnly: true
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: very-secret
          secret:
            secretName: some-secret
```

Further, building the image using gitlab-ci file. And then creating a deployment using this image. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong as when I exec inside the running pod, I can't see the file in the defined destination location.

I don't get any errors, which I usually do if there is an error about wrong source location. I also did go through some more similar questions, so I already checked that the EOL is Unix.

Also, I would like to add some observations,

1. I cannot create the directory as well with  `RUN mkdir -p /src/app/scripts/` This also runs without any error, just not
   reflected inside the pod.

Comment: please you show your deployment yaml

Comment: @Thomas my bad, I should have added it too. I've edited the deployment yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to using an old (wrong) docker image, so changes or updates are not reflected.

Kubernetes does not pull a new image version if the image is already present if the image tag is not "latest". Verify that the image is correctly build by pulling it and running it locally with docker. Use a different tag to force kubernetes to pull the image.

Comment: This exactly fixed my problem. I was fetching it with branch tags, but it wasn't working. After forcing a different tag, it was working as expected.